# Concatenating or adding elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy

i have a numpy array of 27 elements,Im trying concatenate or add all the elements inside the array,but i cant come up with anything right,

I tried,

```
for index,value in enumerate(array):
    np.concatenate(array[index],array[index])
```

but this throws

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I tried

```
array[1]+array[2]+array[3]
```

this works for me, but im not sure how to put this in a loop,
Any suggestions on this front would be really helpful

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
array looks like this

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

   ..., 
   [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
```

Comment: Do you just want the total sum of all of the elements in the array?

Comment: not the sum but all of them tied together

Comment: Thank you so much@PM 2Ring turns out sum was all i wanted,But im curious if i wanted to concatenate or add them in a loop how would i do it?

Comment: "but im not sure how to put this in a loop"... Try something like `for x in range(0,100): previous_value = array[x] + previous_value`. Obviously first you declare `previous_value = 0` so that it "knows" where to start.

Comment: That array has more than 27 elements. What do you mean by "tied together"? It would help if you showed us a small input array and the exact output you want from that input.

Comment: Generally when working with Numpy you should try to avoid explicit loops. Numpy provides many functions and methods which perform the looping for you at compiled speed, which is _much_ faster than a plain Python `for` loop.

Comment: alright ,will keep that in mind

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean by "tied together", but one of the various [Joining arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays) functions may do what you want.

Comment: @PM 2Ring turns out my tied together was to sum them,so dont worry  about it,

Comment: Do you want something like `array.resize(...)`?

Comment: concatenate takes a list of arrays.in your error the second argument is in the axis slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sum over one axis (the first, I think).  Like this:

```
array.sum(axis=0)
```